# The let status change doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, status

First of all, all I want is for the dnd, idle, online status to change!
I have tried so much to fix them but nothing worked! I need help fixing them:

The status does not change to dnd or idle

`${bot.guilds.memberCount}` = is - undefined

`${bot.guilds.size}` = show - 0

```js
const guilds = bot.guilds.find(x => x.id == "651124679662108693");
let games =  [ "Developer | daniel2121#4382",`${bot.guilds.memberCount} Members`,`${bot.guilds.size} The amount of servers the bot is on`];
let status = ["dnd", "online"]

setInterval(function() {

bot.user.setPresence({
    game: {
      name: games[~~(Math.random() * games.length)],
      type: "PLAYING"
    },
    status: status[~~(Math.random() * status.length)]
  });

}, 4000)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk8Fv.png
```

Comment: Well, `bot.guilds` is apparently an array, since you are doing a `find()` on it.  So why would the array have a `memberCount` property?

Answer (score 0):

> The status does not change...

4 seconds will likely rate limit the bot from continuing to change its status. Try using a longer interval.

---

> `${bot.guilds.memberCount}` [is] undefined

[`Client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) ([GuildStore](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildStore) in v12). `bot.guilds.memberCount` is undefined because there isn't a property on a Collection named `memberCount`. There is, however, a [`memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) property of a [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Guild).

To add up all the members your bot is currently serving spanning across *all of its servers*, you can take advantage of the [`Collection.reduce()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=reduce) method:

```js
bot.guilds.reduce((guild, total) => guild.memberCount + total)
```

If you want to display the member count for *only the server you've defined*:

```js
guild.memberCount
```

---

> `${bot.guilds.size}` [shows] 0

Either your bot isn't in any servers, or you're trying to read the bot's guilds before they've been cached. In the case of the latter, set your interval/Cron job only *after* your client has emitted its [`ready`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) event.